# What's the current time?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a website that shows the accurate current time in the browser (should include seconds, GMT is OK)?

Of course to be accurate it would have to correct for transmission delays.

I found two sites [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/gmt.html) and [greenwichmeantime.com](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com) but I have no idea if they are accurate. E.g. when you compare their times it is off by one second (your results may vary depending on network speed, your location, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to time and accuracy on the web, like you mentioned, it's pretty much depending on network speed, location etc. So the options that you found is the most accurate that you can get from where you are.

You can also check the [Network Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) and maybe finding some [public NTP servers](http://www.google.com/#pq=ntp%20servers&xhr=t&q=public+ntp+server) closer to your area that you could use to get more accurate time.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for that thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Time.Gov](http://time.gov) which is provided by the US National Institute of Standards and Technology.  If you need more accurate than that, you would need to go to some GPS type of solution.

Comment: Thanks but time.gov uses Java which I don't have.